# Does Yandex email allow "foreign" users?

Tags: yandex-mail

**BackStory**: I've never been a fan of putting too many eggs in one basket. I had accounts for Gmail, Google Docs, Google+, YouTube, you name it. If it was Google owned, I probably used it. In an attempt to "spread the wealth", I ventured out and started experimenting with some alternatives (Zoho, DuckDuckGo, just to name a few).

Recently I heard a [news report](http://www.reuters.com/article/2012/02/21/us-twitter-yandex-idUSTRE81K08E20120221) about Twitter making a deal with Russian search engine [Yandex](http://www.yandex.com/). I'd never heard of it before, so I gave their search and email service a try. To make a long story short, I really liked what I saw, and I'd like to integrate Yandex into my work flow.

**Question**: Are Americans allowed to use Yandex email? I signed up for an account without any problem, and didn't see any rules against it, so I assume it's okay. But I just wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, of course. As far as I know, there are no restrictions (legal or otherwise) and I was able to use my Yandex mail account from the Europe and China with no problem.

Also, you can write a mail to their support (they usually respond within a few days) so you will get official information.

Answer (score 2):

Yandex officially exists in Russian speaking countries and also in Turkey. They have been aggressively advertising in Turkey and people know that they want to use Turkey to jump into Europe and Americas.

I have been using their e-mail service for quite long time, It fails in terms of usability considered to Gmail. However, for the very same reasons, I keep using my yandex mail as well as Gmail.

Their map service brought StreetView to Turkey, which Google failed to do for years now.